# How does the upload_to work in django model FileField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to submit a form containing a file without django model form.
Can I still use upload_to?

How does it work?

Comment: please be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve. currently this question is too broad.

Comment: Try taking a look at the documentation for file uploads. It may be a solution for what you are looking to accomplish: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: if you are asking about `upload_to` it should mean that you have a `FileField` on a model... in this case you should definitely use a ModelForm

Comment: I'm trying to avoid ModelForm. Does that mean I cannot utilize the upload_to feature?  If not, how does upload_to work? How do I utilize this feature? How does the file gets uploaded to upload_to? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

example:

models.py

```
blabla = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

views.py

```
form = BlaForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```

templates.html

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid ModelForm. Does that mean I cannot utilize the upload_to feature? Thanks!